Express Route Returning JSON Timing Out
I am fairly new to Node, React, and Express, but I have deployed a React app before with a Node server successfully in the past. However, I am deploying on AWS for the first time and it is working a bit differently than my previous host. I was able to get my site showing up, but the Node route that loads the data is timing out. Here is my code on the Node server.
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
var path = require("path");
dotenv.config({ path: ".env" });

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


const mysql = require('mysql2');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER, 
  password: process.env.PASS,
  database: process.env.DB
});
connection.connect((err) => 
{
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error connecting to the database", err);
  }else {
    console.log("Connected to the database!");
  }
})



app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT Min, Max, HeadHousehold, Single, MarriedSeperately, MarriedJointly FROM Tax'; 
    connection.query(sql, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.json(err);  
        
        return res.json(data); 
      })
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port `+process.env.PORT)
})

While I don't think the problem is on the React side, here is the code from React that invokes the data route:
  const[incomes, setIncomes] = useState([]); 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${baseURL}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {setIncomes(data);}
      );
  }, []);

As I said, I'm new to Node and Express and I'm sure there is something basic I am misunderstanding. I need the routing using path to get my site to show up, but then the request to the data route eventually times out without loading the data from the database. I don't believe this is a database issue as even putting a simple response in the data route times out.

Can you show us the errors that you are facing??

The live site is available at link if you want to look at it there. The specific error is net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and the Chrome inspector tells me it failed to load response data because no data was found for the resource with the given identifier.

Can you please put a console.log in the route handler, app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
.., and try the data route from the frontend app. If there is no console.log, as we know, the URL path from the frontend, does not reach the backend route handler.  if that is the case, please use some API testing tools to test and tune the URL path to hit the destined server and the route path. And then once the URL path has been tested and verified, please use the same from the frontend app.

Can you be a little more specific about API testing tools I can use? I had already put a console.log in the data path and the log wasn't appearing, so I think what you are describing could help me. I'm new to all of this, though, so I'm not sure what specifically I can do to "test and tune the URL path".

The point is to isolate the two apps- frontend and backend. And then test the backend first. This app is basically the APIs. "Test and Tune" is to invoke the backend app with any API testing tools and ensure it receives and responds as desired.  Now on this route handler, it simply receives the request, fetches data, and sends it back. At the moment, the access is unrestricted. No user authentication in place. This setup is fine to begin with. Since this is a simple get request, the API testing mentioned earlier can be done with your browser app itself.

Most probably this is what you would have done when you developed this api. Simply type in the URL path in the browser and press ENTER key. If it works then the JSON output would be displayed in the Browser. If the URL path is not hitting the backend, then the URL is to be checked further.

From my Browser, I tested it as this: https://tax.redhawks.us/data , it responded as this // 20240525111127
// https://tax.redhawks.us/data
{
"fatal": true
}

I figured out what the problem was. I was including the port number in the URL I was using to access my /data route, but the port number was not required. Removing the port number fixed the issue. Thanks to those who attempted to help me out!
